# Концепты: как добавить требование для const типа?

Tags: c++, c++20

Пример:

```
template<typename T>
concept SequenceContainer = Container<T> && requires (T a)
{
    { a.front() } -> typename T::reference;
    /* requirements */
};
```

Здесь мы требуем, чтобы тип возвращаемого значения был неконстантной ссылкой. Но если `a` имеет тип `const T` - очевидно, правильно добавить дополнительное требование, указав, что "если `a` имеет тип `const T`, то вызов член-функции `front()` должен вернуть `const_reference`":

```
template<typename T>
concept SequenceContainer = Container<T> && requires (T a, const T b)
{
    { a.front() } -> typename T::reference;
    { b.front() } -> typename T::const_reference;
    /* requirements */
};
```

Вопрос: существует ли способ не указывать второй параметр - `const T b`, а каким-то образом сообщить, что в данном требовании тип `a` следует рассматривать как `const T`? Я не нашел ничего подходящего ни на [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/), ни на [eel.is](http://eel.is/).

Т.е., в идеале хотелось бы что-то вроде:

`{ a.front() const } -> typename T::const_reference;`

Если такого способа нет и нужно делать так, как описано выше (второй параметр с типом const) - при возможности поделитесь ссылкой на соответствующий пункт в стандарте (я про черновик, разумеется).

Comment: Кстати, я слышал `-> typename` вроде убрали из стандарта? Теперь вместо него `std::same_as`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, интересно, не знал. А как быть, если я просто хочу добавить требование для наличия типа? P.S. Извиняюсь за "требование", пользуюсь буквальным переводом, и не знаю, каким русским аналогом заменить. Или это касается только типов возвращаемого значения?

Comment: Не знаю, не разбирался пока с концептами...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, понятно, спасибо за информацию. Буду иметь ввиду.

Comment: Чисто эстетическое замечание: может сразу константность убирать в шаблонном параметре и работать с реальным типом, а const спецификатор добавлять по мере необходимости?

Comment: @MrBin, может быть. Спасибо за замечание. Вообще, видел, в черновиках концептов как-то так и делают.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В голову приходит несколько вариантов:

- `std::as_const(a).front()`
- `std::declval<const T &>().front()`

Comment: Кажется, это то, что нужно. Cпасибо!